# Mass extraction of provides from yum?

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

I have a set of yum repositories.  I have a large collection of rpms from http://pkgs.repoforge.org/.  I don't want to import some of those rpms due to conflicts that they would cause.  I'd like to figure out which of the remaining rpms I can import and also satisfy dependencies.

I can figure out what each rpm provides.  I know that I can do a `yum provides foo` to figure out where to get foo from.  So I can figure out the dependencies.  However yum is slow to startup.  I really don't want to spend a day or so calling it over and over again while I am figuring out my dependency graph.

Is there any way to convince yum to give me a bulk dump of what is available in one call?  Kind of like `yum list all` but instead of listing packages, list everything that is provided by any package that yum knows about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
yum provides '*'
```

and you get list all files from each repository.

Comment: This sounds promising.  I will test that from work on Monday.

Comment: I tested it.  It works.  I wish I had known about this before I kludged together a "good enough" solution for my specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's also:

```
repoquery --tree-provides
repoquery --tree-requires
repoquery --tree-whatrequires
```

...depending on what you want. The latest upstream allows you to output in DOT format too.